# How can I avoid repeating this common code in Django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I have many similar functions in my Django views.py that start off like this:

```
@login_required
def processMyObject(request, myObjectID, myObjectSlug=None):
    logger.info("In processMyObject(myObjectID=%s, myObjectSlug=%s)" % (myObjectID, myObjectSlug))
    try:
        myObject = MyObject.objects.get(id=myObjectID)
    except:
        logger.error("Failed to get MyObject Object by ID")
        raise "Failed to get MyObject Object by ID"

    if myObjectSlug != None and myObject.slug != myObjectSlug:
        logger.error("myObjectSlug '%s' doesn't match myObject #%s's slug" % (myObjectSlug, myObject.id))
        raise "myObjectSlug '%s' doesn't match myObject #%s's slug" % (myObjectSlug, myObject.id)
```

Each of these functions has the same argument signature and contains the same chunk of code at the top, but then goes on to do implement some unique functionality. However this is common code in each one of them. It seems like a horrible violation of DRY for me to have typed the same code so many multiple times.

How can I use inheritance or some other technique to elegantly factor out this code so that it only appears once but is used in each of these view functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can write decorator that recieves the MyObjectId and slug from view as parameter. logs the info line and raises an error if object is missing.

Just check information about function decorators and read django code for examples. For example, look up the code for the decorator you are already using (login_required) and look up the user_passes_test decorator in django.contrib.auth.decorators. That is probably the best real example for your case.

And then use the decorator in front of each view that needs it - just like you are using @login_required